# how to display Multi VAT on invoice

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have multi VAT such as 8% and 16% which I add it to the item master under a table called VAT and set any item there by its tax, for instance KITKAT sell price 1 and vat 8 and I have Milk sell price 2 and vat 16 
so the invoice needs to display the vat at the end of the invoice so I write the below with no result.
P.S the below only to display and calculate the VAT on the invoice.

```
Dim pConn2 As SqlConnection = Code.GetConnection()
Dim sql3 As String = "select std_cost from sc_mast where tax='8'"
Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(sql3, pConn2)
Dim dr3 As SqlDataReader
dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader
dr3.Read()
Dim tax8 As Decimal
If tax8 = 8 Then
    tax8 = sql3 / (1 + (8 / 100))
End If

gp3.AddString("Tax 8%: ", 
              Total_Font.FontFamily,
              Total_Font.Style.Bold,
              Total_Font.Size,
              New Rectangle(x3, y3 + 140, 100, 30), ft)

gp3.AddString((Format(tax8, "0.000")),
               Price_Font.FontFamily,
               Price_Font.Style.Bold,
               Price_Font.Size,
               New Rectangle(price_X + 10, y3 + 140, price_width, 30), 
               ftprices)
```

Comment: You have several conversions going on.  `where tax='8'"` implies tax is string/text, but later it  is a number: `tax8 = 8`.  `Tax8` can never be 8 in that code because it was just declared the line before: `Dim tax8 As Decimal`